# SQL Server drop temporary table has odd behaviour

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to understand some odd SQL Server behaviour around dropping temporary tables. The following code results in an error on line 3, saying "There is already an object named '#Table1' in the database."

Why does the table seem to still exist after it's dropped?

```
create table #Table1 (Col int)
drop table #Table1
create table #Table1 (Col int)
drop table #Table1
```

I tried a few other code samples as a sanity check.

```
create table #Table1 (Col int)
drop table #Table1
select * from #Table1
```

Selecting from the dropped temporary table fails, as expected.

```
create table Table1 (Col int)
drop table Table1
create table Table1 (Col int)
drop table Table1
```

Dropping and recreating a non-temporary table succeeds, as expected.

```
begin tran
create table #Table1 (Col int)
drop table #Table1
commit
begin tran
create table #Table1 (Col int)
drop table #Table1
commit
```

Wrapping the pairs of lines in transactions makes no difference; it still fails.

```
create table #Table1 (Col int)
drop table #Table1
go
create table #Table1 (Col int)
drop table #Table1
```

Inserting a "GO" between the pairs of lines makes the whole script succeed.

Why does this only fail for temporary tables?

Comment: Batch and statement (re-)compilation. The rules for this are, well, not intuitive. The behavior has changed across SQL Server versions; most notably from 2000 to 2005. Creating, using and dropping a table in a single batch is something that didn't use to work at all, and now works more or less as an accident of how statement recompilation happens -- an accident that was not extended to temporary tables, as the rules for these are even *more* complicated, because of the need for them to work across stored procedure invocations. I pity the soul who has to turn this into a full answer.

Comment: it would be nice if we could have conditional select into too eg if ,<cond> begin select col1, col2 into #temp1 from tabA end else begin select col1, col2 into #temp1 from tabB end